# Tagmanager Jquery - How have the ajax file have to look like?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Tagsmanager for JQuery: http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager

Its possible to push tags via Ajax:

```
   jQuery(".tm-input").tagsManager({
        AjaxPush: '/ajax/countries/push',
        AjaxPushAllTags: true,
        AjaxPushParameters: { 'authToken': 'foobar' }
    });
```

But what does the file in /ajax/countries/push have to look like to get tags? Could someone post an example please? It would be great if this file could be PHP.

Answer (score 0):

`AjaxPush` doesn't *get* the tags at all, it's for setting tags. It needs to accept a POST with an array of tags coming on on the `tag` parameter.